# Smallest Missing Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I'd like some insight on the following code. The problem says, devise an algorithm that finds the smallest missing number in an array

My Approach:

```
def small(arr: list) -> int:
    s = {*arr}
    i = 1
    while True:
        if i not in s:
            return i
        i += 1
```

Easy right?
The problem is this uses space complexity of (n) when I create that extra set

Better Approach:

```
# Linear time routine for partitioning step of Quicksort
def partition(arr):
    pIndex = 0
 
    # each time we find a positive number, `pIndex` is incremented, and
    # that element would be placed before the pivot
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] > 0:        # pivot is 0:
            arr[i], arr[pIndex] = arr[pIndex], arr[i]
            pIndex += 1
 
    # return index of the first non-positive number
    return pIndex
 
 
# Function to find the smallest missing positive number from an unsorted array
def findSmallestMissing(arr, n):
 
    # Case 1. The missing number is in range 1 to `n`
 
    # do for each array element
    for i in range(n):
 
        # get the value of the current element
        val = abs(arr[i])
 
        # make element at index `val-1` negative if it is positive
        if val - 1 < n and arr[val - 1] >= 0:
            arr[val - 1] = -arr[val - 1]
 
    # check for missing numbers from 1 to `n`
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i] > 0:
            return i + 1
 
    # Case 2. If numbers from 1 to `n` are present in the array,
    # then the missing number is `n+1` e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4] —> 5
 
    return n + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [1, 4, 2, -1, 6, 5]
    k = partition(arr)
    print("The smallest positive missing number is", 
    findSmallestMissing(arr, k))
```

I don't understand why do we need

```
if val - 1 < n and arr[val - 1] >= 0:
    arr[val - 1] = -arr[val - 1]
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the `partition` function in your question? It never gets called...

Comment: I've update the question, Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findSmallestMissing` is really very similar to your set-based solution. The difference is that it uses the sign-bit in the input array as that set. That sign has nothing to do with the value that is stored at the same spot, but with the *index*. If the sign bit is set it means: I have encountered a value that is this *index* (after translating a value to an index by subtracting one).

The code you asked about:

```
if val - 1 < n and arr[val - 1] >= 0:
    arr[val - 1] = -arr[val - 1]
```

First of all, the subtraction of one is there to covert a 1-based *value* to a 0-based *index*.

Since we use the array also as a set, this code first checks that the index is in range (of the "set") and then it checks that this index is not yet in the set, i.e. the sign bit at that index is still 0. If so, we add the index to the set, i.e. we *set* the sign bit at that index to 1.

All in all, one may argue that we cheat here: it is as if we didn't allocate extra memory for maintaining a set, but in reality we used an unused bit. In *theory* this means we still use extra memory, while in practice that memory was already allocated, but not used. The algorithm assumes that the none of the values in the array are negative.